# How to solve this program better

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

The following question was from a recent Programming Contest.

**GCD Game**

Life and death, win or lose - both have two sides to each other. And that's what Arjit and Chandu Don are fighting about. They are tired of gang-wars between each other, and thus decide to settle like men in a field, of Mathematics.
But even while going to play the game of Mathematics, they have not given up on their tactics of hurting each other. So, Arjit carries a number of rubber bullets with himself, and Chandu Don carries b number of rubber bullets. Since, Little Chandu is a more dangerous gangster of the two, he decides to give the first chance to Arjit.
The way they’re going to decide who wins the entire land of HEpur is by playing the age-old game of GCD-DCG. The first one to end up with only 1 bullet is going to lose.
This is how the game progresses:

```
1. If GCD (a, b) is greater than 1, then, the player can: 
    a.) Subtract 1 from opposite player’s bullets. **OR** 
    b.) Divide the number of bullets of opposite player by GCD (a, b). 
2. If GCD (a, b) is equal to 1, then, the player can: 
    a.) Subtract 1 from the opposite player’s bullets.

Note : Player can choose only one move out of two if GCD(A,B) > 1 .

The one who ends up with only one bullet loses the battle, 
and his life, and the land of HEpur.
```

Determine who is going to rule, once and for all!

Input:
First line contains number of test cases T, next T lines contains two numbers A and B taken by Arjit and Chandu Don respectively.

Output:
Print the name of winner of the game in case of draw print Draw.
Constraints

```
1 <= T <= 1000
1 <= A <= 1000
1 <= B <= 1000
```

Problem Statement Credit : Arjit Srivastava.

```
Sample Input
4
2 1
3 4
5 5
1 1
Sample Output
Arjit
Chandu Don
Arjit
Draw
```

I am adding my solution here:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class TestClass 
{
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception 
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int noOfTestCases = Integer.parseInt( br.readLine() );

        for( int inx = 0; inx < noOfTestCases; ++inx )
        {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer( br.readLine() );

            int a = 0;
            int b = 0;

            while( st.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                a = Integer.parseInt( st.nextToken() );
                b = Integer.parseInt( st.nextToken() );                     
            }

            doStuff( a, b, true);
        }
    }

    private static boolean doStuff(int a, int b, boolean arjitInPlay ) 
    {
        if( a == 1 && b == 1 )
        {
            System.out.println( "Draw" );
            return true;
        }

        if( a == 1 )
        {
            System.out.println( "Chandu Don" );
            return true;
        }

        if( b == 1 )
        {
            System.out.println( "Arjit" );
            return true;
        }

        int result = getGCD( a, b );


        if( arjitInPlay )
        {
            if( result > 1 )
            {
                return doStuff( a, b - 1, !arjitInPlay ) || doStuff( a, b / result, !arjitInPlay );
            }
            else if ( result == 1 )
            {
                return doStuff( a, b - 1, !arjitInPlay );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if( result > 1 )
            {
                return doStuff( a - 1, b, !arjitInPlay ) || doStuff( a / result, b, !arjitInPlay );
            }
            else if ( result == 1 )
            {
                return doStuff( a - 1, b, !arjitInPlay );
            }               
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static int getGCD(int a, int b) 
    {
        if (b == 0)
        {
            return a;
        }
        return getGCD(b, a % b);
    }
}
```

I have two questions here:

- Is recursion the best data structure that can be employed here?. Or is this calling for another data structure or algorithm class.
- There is a concept called pruning right..where few paths are cut off after deciding that they are not going to yield good results. Can someone please help me how to prune the above code [ better, than short-circuiting ].
- What could be wrong with this code?. 1 of 3 tests is passing. The other two are failing.

thanks,
Pavan.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the tests that are failing, instead of making us all guess.

Comment: @DavidWallace I am afraid that is not possible. Thing is they are contest test cases which are not exposed.

Comment: So you're basically asking the SO community to test your code for you, and tell you what the bugs are?  I don't think anyone really has the time to do that, but I might be wrong.  If you could be specific about exactly what failed, then somebody would almost certainly be able to tell you why.  But in its present form, I don't think you're going to get any answers to your question at all.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried solving the problem on any automatic judge system yet, but I have following suggestions:

Suppose they're playing optimally.

Using recursion is totally fine according to the constraints, but your implementation has a bug. What your code doing is simply **each turn, each user removes 1 bullet from the opposite** and I think NONE of the second function call in your short-circuit has been executed. In other words, **your code will declare the one who has more bullets as a winner**. You can try `8 5` as input. Your code outputs 'Arjit' but actually it should be 'Chandu Don'.

IMHO, instead of doing a DFS-like reach-1-and-finish-the-computation approach, the best way to solve the problem is using a 3D array `win[i][j][k]`, denoting whether player `k` will win when he is supposed to make a movement when player 0 has `i` bullets and player 1 has `j` bullets. Note that draw game can only happen when input is `1 1`.

Take player 0 as an example, `win[i][j][0]` is `True` if and only if either `win[i][j - 1][1]` is `False` or `win[i][j / gcd(i, j)][1]` (if `gcd(i, j) > 1`) is `False`. And the calculation for player 1 is similar.

I know this is basically the same idea to yours, but by doing so, computation results can be cached for all `a b` therefore the future queries/access will be very fast.